# VBScript: Get logged on windows user instead of executing one

Tags: deployment, vbscript

I need to perform a small inventory in our network.
So I wrote a VBScript which I wanted to deploy with our deployment system.
My problem now is: The script is executed in the context of the AD system user.

So this lines:

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strOutput = strOutput & ";" & objNetwork.UserName
```

Wont return the logged on user but the AD system user running the script.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For future google users:
I solved it with this little gem: http://officewarfare.net/index.php/owexec/

- Copy the vbs file to the local hdd
- start the script via owexec (with parameter -c localhost)

Thats it